# how to conduct a speed and performance test on a platform with authentication details

Tags: performance, pagespeed-insights, software-quality, webpagetest

how to conduct a speed and performance test on a platform with authentication details using google page speed insights but i can't move past the login page

I tried the google page speed insights tool and webpage test tool but i can't get past the authentication page of the platform being tested

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

PageSpeed Insights doesn't support this, but you can use Lighthouse in Chrome Dev Tools to test the page locally after you have logged in.

WebPageTest offers [scripting functionality](https://nooshu.com/blog/2020/12/31/how-to-run-a-webpagetest-test/#script-tab) where you can follow a flow to enter a username and password and load a page, or set cookies to be logged in automatically (just ensure no sensitive data is stored in the public test and expire the login/cookies immeadiately after use).

Alternatively, you could add a url param which bypasses the login for testing - for example, serves non-sensitive dummy data to simulate a logged in user. This would work for both tools.